# How do I get the select box values in YUI 3?

Tags: yui, yui3

In YUI 3 I have a node that is my select box:

```
Y.get('#regionSelect');
```

How do I get the `<option>` values that are currently selected (even if there are more than one?) Also, is there a tutorial out there that tells me explicitly how to do this (I don't want to serialize a whole form)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you have the selector, you can chain `get` and `each`

```
Y.get("#regionSelect").get("options").each( function() {
   // this = option from the select
   var selected = this.get('selected');
   var value  = this.get('value');
   var text = this.get('text');
   // apply secret sauce here
});
```

I've just been using the demos/examples on http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/ to figure things out.

Comment: Thanks! Where does it say how to get attributes?

Comment: You are welcome.
Any JavaScript tutorial about the DOM should have the attribs for the select and option objects (as well as all the others).  Those aren't YUI specific but part of the DOM.  For instance: http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_obj_select.asp

Comment: The 'selected' and 'text' are actually selectors, not attributes. Left that out....

Comment: Did you mean "Y.one("#regionSelect")"? Worked for me when I used .one() instead of .get()

Answer (score 8):

// Selected Value

- Y.one('#regionSelect')._node.value;
- Y.one('#regionSelect').get('value');

// Selected Index

- Y.one('#regionSelect')._node.selectedIndex;
- Y.one('#regionSelect').get('selectedIndex');

Comment: this always returns an empty string...doesn't one have to get the options and then their value ?

Comment: The "_node" property is not part of the YUI Node API. You should never rely on it.

Comment: "_node" is *visual private* object property based on YUI coding standards

Answer (score 5):

You might not need to iterate through all options if you need just a selected one:

```
var index = Y.get("#regionSelect").get('selectedIndex');
var value = Y.get("#regionSelect").get("options").item(index).getAttribute('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use this. Require `selector-css3` module to support IE.

```
YUI().use("selector-css3", "node", function (Y) {
    var text = Y.one("#ownerSelector option:checked").get("text");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/neosoyn/r8crW/